# Play Framework: JPA and Lazy Loading

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, lazy-loading

I am using Play Framework v.2.6.3 , and the JPA solution for SQL access.

When I set the FetchType.Lazy on my entities, I get the following error message:

> play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: models.UserImp.goods, could not initialize proxy - no Session

If you read Play Docs, there it says:

> This may mean that your domain object (aggregate root, in DDD terms) has an internal reference to the repository and calls it to return lists of entities and value objects, rather than holding a session open and using JPA based lazy loading.

So, my question is: Whats the best solution to work with Lazy fetching?

I dont get, how do I need to deal with this.

Can you give me an example?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

FetchType.Lazy loading denotes that element of your entity on which FetchType is mentioned can be used inside the session only.you need to use that elment inside the transaction only.

Comment: I know the principle that involves Lazy Fetching and yes, this issue fixed when I set an Eager Fetching.  But, why in DDD terms do I not to use this Lazy Loading and always use Eager Fetching? Does Play Framework uses this principle as the doc says? What do I need to use?